# Chaining the delay function

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I want to run delay function as part of my underscore chain.
It seems like delay function is only able to work with explicit argument passed - not the wrapper object.
This code does not work (undefined is not a function exception):

```
var message = function (text) {
                var txt = text;
                var show = function () { alert(txt); };
                return {
                    Text: txt,
                    Show: show
                };
            };

 _.chain(new message("hello")).delay(function(m) { m.Show(); }, 1000);
```

This code works:

```
var x = _.chain(new message("hello")).value();
            _.delay(function (m) { m.Show(); }, 1000, x);
```

Is there a way to make delay work inside of a longer functional expression?

E.g. I want to defer viewmodel instance creation and then delay binding to UI by X ms.

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't look like intended purpose of chains. Maybe you should take a look at promises. For example https://github.com/kriskowal/q or you can try the ones built in jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What `chain()` does in underscore is just pipe its argument through all the following functions, passing it as first argument to those functions.

Since first argument to `delay()` should be a function then to achieve functionality you desire you'd have to do something like this:

```
_.chain(function(m) {
        m.Show();
    }).delay(1000, new message("hello"));
```

but I guess it doesn't have the structure you desire.

So you can't use `delay()` directly, but you can use it via `tap()`:

```
_.chain(new message("hello"))
    .tap(function(m) {
        _.delay(function() {
            m.Show();
        }, 1000);
    })
```

or even more concisely with use of `tap()` and `bind()`:

```
_.chain(new message("hello"))
    .tap(_.delay.bind(null, function(m) {
            m.Show();
    }, 1000))
```

If you wan't to pass in collection to `chain()` and do a `delay()` for every element of the collection use `each()` instead of `tap()`.

---

The following is not an answer as it uses rather [github.com/kriskowal/q](http://github.com/kriskowal/q) promises than underscore.js but that's what I think you are trying to do, namely push something through a pipeline of operations some of them async:

```
var message = function (text) {
                var txt = text;
                var show = function () { alert(txt); };
                return {
                    Text: txt,
                    Show: show
                };
            };


function delay(time) {
    return function(m) {
        var next = Q.defer();
        setTimeout(function() {
            next.resolve(m);
        }, 1000);
        return next.promise;
    }
}

Q.when(new message("hello"))
    .then(delay(1000))
    .then(function(m) {
        m.Show();
    });
```

Comment: You are right. It is rather a promises flow. I was just trying to save introducing another library like Q/when, so I would probably go with the tap + bind solution meanwhile or some extension to make it reusable. e.g. _.lazy and _.delayedBind wrappers

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of _.delay must be a function, but u pass a instance if message class (object).
f.e.

```
var foo = function(){
   console.log('FOO');
}
_.chain(foo).delay(200);
```

And to use chain in your case is overhead. Try something like that:

```
var showMsg = function(){
    var msg = new message("hello");
    msg.Show();
};

_(showMsg).delay(200);
```

Comment: When I pass it an instance of message class it does work (second version). It doesn't work with _ wrapper object. I posted this case just for example - as I mentioned in E.g. I have a more complex scenario of building viewmodels, preloading data ,binding them to views and switching between groups of visible views